# How to Update numeric rows of Data in Oracle with use of a Trigger

Tags: triggers, oracle10g, row

How do I write a query to update my rows 'S'. I would like to update the current Primary key to change the number of it. I am not sure if I need a sub-query. 
Would updating score, use the same method to update "S"? 
"S" indicates student number, "C" indicates course number.

My tried but failed query is

```
update grades set s = 114 where s = 100;
```

The 'set s' is what I want to update into and the 'where s' is looking for the row with that set 's' number. Right?

Here is my query, trigger, and select * from grades looks like.

```
create table grades (
S varchar2(12),
C varchar2(10),
Score number(3,0),
Letter_Grade char(1),
Constraint pk_grades primary key (S),
Constraint CK_grades check (score between 0 and 100)
constraint lg_grades check (letter_grade  in ('A','B','C','D','F'))
);

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MARK_BU
BEFORE UPDATE OF score ON grades
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
:NEW.letter_grade :=
 CASE 
    WHEN :NEW.score >= 80 THEN 'A'
    WHEN :NEW.score >= 70 THEN 'B'
    WHEN :NEW.score >= 60 THEN 'C'
    WHEN :NEW.score >= 50 THEN 'D'
   ELSE 'F'
END ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Numeric_grade was updated to:    ' || :NEW.score);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Letter_grade was calculated to be:' || :NEW.letter_grade);
END;

S            C               SCORE L
------------ ---------- ---------- -
100          CST8255            49 F
101          CST8255            59 D
102          CST8255            69 C
103          CST8255            79 B
104          CST8255            89 A
```

Comment: What "failed" about the query?  It appears to be syntactically valid and would update any row in the table that has a `SCORE` of 89 to a `SCORE` of 95.  So it would update the row where `S` is 104 and C is `CST8255` and change the `SCORE` to 95.

Comment: Oh I mixed confused myself. Woah this is easy.

Comment: It is syntactically legal to change a primary key value though doing so would generally indicate that the primary key was poorly chosen.  If there are any child tables that have foreign keys that reference the primary key value you are changing, those constraints would generate errors if you changed the parent column.

Comment: @GivenPie You can update primary key values as long as there is no constraint on it and as long as it is still unique!

Comment: @Kevin, by definition a primary key is a constraint. You can update a pk as long as you don't create a duplicate, thus invalidating the constraint. I believe you also can't update the pk on an IOT...

Comment: @GivenPie, you're storing data as a varchar2 and updating with numeric values. If they're numbers it's better to keep them as such. It stops people adding non-numeric characters in later when you don't want them to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update grades set s = 114 where s = 100;
```

Is correct it will work.